# How to navigate in a ListBox by VBA code?

Tags: ms-access

I want to insert some buttons for navigation in a access form. The user should be able to use this buttons to navigate up and down in a ListBox. The ListBox is not multiselectable.

This is my Code for the previous Button:

```
Private Sub btnPrev_Click()
    myListBox.SetFocus
    myListBox.ListIndex = MyLib.max(0, myListBox.ListIndex - 1)
    btnPrev.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Problems with the code:

1. I have to set the focus to the ListBox. If not I get the error 7777 (Wrong usage of property ListIndex)
2. The ListBox must be active, cause SetFocus will not work if inactive.
3. The ListBox must not be locked

What is best practise, to navigate with vba in a ListBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the `.ListIndex` property to move around.

Use `.ItemsSelected` and `.Selected` instead:

```
Private Sub btnPrev_Click()
    With myListBox
        If .ItemsSelected.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub 'Can't move to previous if nothing is selected
        Dim currentPosition As Long
        currentPosition = .ItemsSelected(0) 'Current position = position of first selected item
        If currentPosition = 0 Then Exit Sub 'Can't move lower than 0
        .Selected(currentPosition) = False 'Deselect current item
        .Selected(currentPosition-1) = True 'Select previous item
    End With
End Sub
```

Deselecting the current item can be omitted when the listbox is not multi-select, since selecting an item deselects all others when that's the case.

Comment: Works very good, thank you. Only Problem (for me) is that I have to overthink my logic when the selected record changes. The form should switch to that record too. Until now, I was using the click-event for that, but that is not fired anymore.

Comment: Eh... Just call the sub: `myListbox_Click` or `Call myListbox_Click()`. However, it's a bad design practice to call event handlers without an event, you should have a separate sub to move the record, and call that whenever needed (in the event handler, at the end of this sub).

Comment: yes, I will call "updateFormData" at the end of the button code and in the click event.